# supertest failing with ECONNRESET

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm working on a Node.js project and trying to write test cases for the app.
The endpoints are working perfectly fine when I run them in Postman. But when I run the test cases, some of them, (Usually the first one in the order) fails with the error

```
 - Error: read ECONNRESET
```

I have tried debugging it, searched for a potential solution, but I'm unable to fix it. I'm working with jasmine/supertest for the first time. Maybe I'm missing something I'm unable to anticipate but I haven't been able to find out the issue.
Can anybody help me out with this? Thanks a bunch in advance.

Here is my test code.

```
 it('Gets Users List', async() => {
     const response = await request.get('/users')
    

    expect(response.status).toBe(200);
    
})
```

and my Controller function

```
export const index = async (req:Request, res: Response) => {
try {
    const users : DataObject = await model.index()
    
    res.status(users.status);
    res.json(users.data);

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(NOT_FOUND);
    res.json(error);
  }
}
```

The peculiar behavior that I observed is when I add another method before this one, then this method works fine and the first one returns the same error.
I assume the first call is rejected due to the fact that connection was not established yet? I'm not sure though.

Anybody familiar with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like the copy of the current one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948296/mocha-supertest-econnreset

Comment: I'm already using supertest as explained in this post. It doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Possible race condition? I was running into ECONNRESET issues when using request.post for api controllers that work flawlessly in postman and through our app. The ECONNRESET would occur when I was validating incoming parameters before proceeding with business logic.

The only variant I could determine between which res.send() worked and didn't was time... so I inserted a 1000ms sleep and my ECONNRESET errors stopped.

Answer (score 0):

So others can benefit, in the comments @rwheadon mentioned it was a race condition for them.

Can confirm that was the case for us as well.

This is the final working code for us:

```
it('should fail without a valid token', (done) => {
  // After multiple hours of trying to get it to work, we figured out that
  // _in this specific test_, the file being consumed on the same tick as
  // the request being sent causes an issue where the server has an
  // ECONNRESET error.  This is not an issue normally, or in any other
  // test, only for this test.
  const file = fs.createReadStream(path.join(process.cwd(), uploadExcelFile));
  setTimeout(() => {
    localSuperTest
      .post(`/upload-redeem-codes`)
      .attach('file', file)
      .expect(401)
      .end((err: any, res: any) => {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        assert.equal(res.body.message, 'not authorized');
        done();
      });
    });
  });
```

Somehow, there is a race condition in tests when using `.attach()` with supertest.

The main point, we believe, is that reading the file, and then consuming the file (with the `.attach('file', file)`, have to be on two different ticks in the callback loop.

I hope that saves a poor soul several hours of investigation.